# Ionic2 SMS not working

Tags: typescript, ionic2, sms

I am trying to get SMS messages using the Ionic SMS plugin, but its not working. I installed this dependency:

```
"@ionic-native/sms": "^4.2.1"
```

Is there any problem with country codes for SMS?

Here is my `.ts` code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SMS } from '@ionic-native/sms';


@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
number: string = "";
 message: string = "";

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public sms: SMS,private toastCtrl: 
 ToastController) {}

sendTextMessage() {
this.sms.send(this.number, this.message).then((result) => {
  let successToast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: "Text message sent successfully! :)",
    duration: 3000
  })
  successToast.present();
}, (error) => {
  let errorToast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: "Text message not sent. :(",
    duration: 3000
  })
  errorToast.present();
});
}

}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-card>
<ion-item>
   <ion-label stacked>Phone Number</ion-label>
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="number" type="text"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label stacked>Message</ion-label>
  <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="message"></ion-textarea>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <button ion-button icon-left clear item-right (click)="sendTextMessage()">
  <ion-icon name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
  Send
</button>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: what do you mean not working? any errors?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please see [ask].

Comment: there is no error showing, its build successfully, Not arriving any SMS when i test with real device also.